# Basic Digest and Authentication in Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, https, amazon-sns

My purpose is to fan out messages to HTTPS endpoint from SNS topic. I have my backend code in spring-boot and I have enabled Basic Authentication to secure my endpoint.

Let's say the URL to which I will be posting message from SNS Topic is

```
https:abcd.com/test
```

Credentials are:

Username: user

Password: password

While subscribing this endpoint what URL shall I mention in SNS topic?

Should it be:

```
https:user:password@abcd.com/test
```

or it should be something else?

I've read the official aws doc but it wasn't clear to me. I also read somewhere that you can't add any additional headers in the POST request that SNS will send. In that case, how will the Authorization header be added? Kindly help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to use Basic Auth? The docs are not very clear